# Java Project Reactor Parallel Stream Ignore Errors

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

We have an application where we have multiple sinks for different use cases, and we are publishing data to those sinks at certain intervals.

```
protected Map<String, Sinks.Many<String>> sinks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
private void init(){    
    sinks.putIfAbsent(getCode(), Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer());
    sinks.get(getCode()).asFlux().parallel().runOn(scheduler).subscribe(message -> handleMessage(message));
}
```

Whenever `handleMessage(message)` throws an exception - the processing stops, the sinks do not work any more.
I tried adding try/catch block to the subscribe and that works fine, but I am looking for a more elegant solution (if it exists)

```
.subscribe(message -> { 
   try {
      handleMessage(message)
   } catch(Exception e) {
      // DO SOMETHING
   });
```

Does something better exist that is built into the library itself that would support ParallelFlux ignoring of the exceptions?
Thanks a lot!